# Error: bad receiver type 'CGSize' (aka 'struct CGSize') | Xcode 6.4 | iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, xcode6

I'm having a problem with a deprecated method, I'm trying to change it for one working right now, but no luck, does someone knows how to solve this?

The problem is that I'm working on a code that is not mine, so I don't get it very well.

This is the original code (**the one deprecated**):

```
CGFloat remainingHeight = bounds.size.height - totalSize.height - kPadding - 4 * margin; 
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(maxWidth, remainingHeight);
CGSize detailsLabelSize = [detailsLabel.text sizeWithFont:detailsLabel.font
                            constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:detailsLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

This is my solution (**that throw the error**):

```
CGFloat remainingHeight = bounds.size.height - totalSize.height - kPadding - 4 * margin; 
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(maxWidth, remainingHeight);
CGSize detailsLabelSize = [[detailsLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:detailsLabel.font}]constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:detailsLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

The error is in the title (**bad receiver type 'CGSize' (aka 'struct CGSize')**)

Thank you so much!

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: @Sebydd the one in the title

Comment: Where are you getting 'maxSize' from?

Comment: one line before that one, let me add it

Comment: Are you receiving it at run time?

Comment: The error? no, it's not at run time, I can't run it due to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method in your implementation file:

```
-(CGSize)frameForText:(NSString*)text sizeWithFont:(UIFont*)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode  {

    NSMutableParagraphStyle * paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode;

    NSDictionary * attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:font,
                                  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle
                                  };


    CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:size
                                         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                      attributes:attributes
                                         context:nil];
    return textRect.size;
}
```

And then change your code to:

```
CGSize detailsLabelSize = [self frameForText:detailsLabel.text sizeWithFont:detailsLabel.font constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:detailsLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line:

```
CGSize detailsLabelSize = [[detailsLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:detailsLabel.font}]constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:detailsLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

`[detailsLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:detailsLabel.font}]` returns a `CGSize` which is not an object. You are then attempting to call `constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:detailsLabel.lineBreakMode` on this `CGSize`, which is impossible, because it's not an object.

Comment: Yeah, I thought something similar (At least I'm not as lost as I thought jaja), but I don't know how to solve it, sorry, I'm too new at Objective-C :c Any recommendation?